# How to click First li tag in this case

Tags: jquery

On Page load i want to make 1D selected as default

I have tried this way

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("ul.menu li a:first").click();
});

$("ul.menu li").click(function() {
  var tabclicked = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  alert(tabclicked);
});
```

But could you please tell me why the alert is not getting displayed ??

This is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/gr1L23us/3/

Comment: You aren't invoking a click event anywhere. `click()` is simply binding an event when a click happens, not mimicking an actual click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it this way: https://jsfiddle.net/gr1L23us/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.menu li a").click(function() {
    var tabclicked = $(this).attr("href");
    alert(tabclicked);
  });

  $("ul.menu li:first-child a").click();
});
```

1. change the positions of the event listener function (which is the one with the alert) and then the event
2. use `:first-child` as a selector on `<li>`
3. change the `click` event to fire on an `<a>`

another possible application would be the `jquery` way: https://jsfiddle.net/gr1L23us/8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.menu li a").click(function() {
    var tabclicked = $(this).attr("href");
    alert(tabclicked);
  });

  $("ul.menu li").first().find('a').click();
});
```

by using the [.first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) to select the first `<li>` and [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to go deeoper on the `<a>` link inside to fire the `click`

Answer (score 3):

you can trigger click the first li  but you should do the trigger after the li click event not before it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.menu > li").click(function() {
    var tabclicked = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    alert(tabclicked);
  });
  $("ul.menu > li:first").trigger('click');
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/gr1L23us/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Put your click function within the document ready call, before `$("ul.menu li a:first").click();`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.menu li").click(function() {
    var tabclicked = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    alert(tabclicked);
  });
  $("ul.menu li a:first").click();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gr1L23us/6/)**